# Apache2 PassEnv on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, environment-variables

I want to pass a system-wide variable to Apache so I can pass it to executed scripts using PassEnv. Basically a script executed Apache executes a shell script, that shell script wont run without the variable being set.

But Ubuntu devs did this in the startup script:

`ENV="env -i LANG=C PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"`

Resulting in variables from /etc/environment to be discarded. Can I fix this without modifying the startup script?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Turns out you can pass along vars in /etc/apache2/envvars. Still sucks though.</strike>

Nope. The value stays empty.